# OpenSSH SFTP Server/Integromat Timed out waiting for a handshake

Tags: server, ssh, openssh, sftp

I'm trying to use Integromat and SFTP to sync my Google Drive to a folder on my desktop. I'm open to other methods of accomplishing this goal, but I wanted to do a SFTP server as a learning experience.

I followed a tutorial to create the server using OpenSSH and used a website to find my public IP.

I'm at a stand-still because I can't get a handshake between my sftp server and integromat. Here's a look at my OpenSSH status.

```
the1jonbrown@jon-desktop:~$ service ssh status
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-04-18 00:04:49 EDT; 52min ago
  Process: 1882 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1878 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4576 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4577 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─4577 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Apr 18 00:04:49 jon-desktop systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Apr 18 00:04:49 jon-desktop sshd[4577]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Apr 18 00:04:49 jon-desktop sshd[4577]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Apr 18 00:04:49 jon-desktop systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
the1jonbrown@jon-desktop:~$
```

I doubt that this is the whole story. I need to test to see if my server is active, I'm not sure if this status is proving that. This is what I have in my sshd_config file UsePAM:

```
UsePAM yes

"Match group gdrive
ChrootDirectory /var/GoogleDrive
X11Forwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp"
```

I also edited this guy:

```
Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help, I'm new to SFTP.

Jon Brown

Comment: You wrote `used a website to find my public IP.` You do not have public ip on server. Do you do port forwarding on router, if your router have public ip on wan port, to your server?

Comment: No I haven't done that. My router probably has a public IP on its wan port. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Depends on your ISP and router. Sorry, to many options to explain.